# Send value from controller with ajax Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

i have javascript like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        var menu_id = this.value;
        if(this.checked) var statusvalue = "On";
        else var statusvalue = "Off";
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "admin/menu/editstatus",
            data    : "id=" + menu_id + "&value=" + statusvalue,
            success : function(data){
                $("#testing").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my controller named menu and have function editstatus()

```
public function editstatus()
{
    $data = "asd";
    echo $data;
}
```

but textbox with id testing not writen anything

Comment: code seems to be fine, can you check response in net call of browser??

Comment: So where's the actual problem in `controller` or in `ajax`

Comment: check url weather is reach to right page or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your url did not found.Try using base url

```
<?php echo base_url()?>admin/menu/editstatus
```

Comment: you need base_url() for getting the full url

Answer (score 1):

change ajax function like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        var menu_id = this.value;
        if(this.checked)
         {
          var statusvalue = "On";
         } 
        else 
        {
          var statusvalue = "Off";
        }
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/menu/editstatus",
            data    :{ 
                     id:menu_id,
                     value:statusvalue
                      }
            success : function(data){
               $("#testing").val(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i use your code, the textbox fills with this:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> <title>Admin Panel</title> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/big/img/Logo.png"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/big/css/admin-leftmenu.css"> <script src="http://localhost/big/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> <script src="htt.............. etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

Corrected code:

```
$("#testing").val(data);
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: i change to .val, and all of my code show in textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
public function editstatus()
{
    $data = "asd";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

if $data is an array form e.g `$data=array('name'=>'abd','id'=>'12')` then ,
in Java script access like ,data.name or data.id